# Array[i] = scnr.nextInt(); causing Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I can't figure out why i keep getting this error. The code is supposed to output the middle integer when given a list of integers in an odd number. A negative value at the end ends the input. This line of code is throwing a main exception error and I can not figure out why. I have also tried using a temp varialbe. userValues[i]=scnr.nextInt();

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:16)
```

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] userValues = new int[10];  // Set of data specified by the user 
      int count = 0;
      int temp = 0;



for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
      if (scnr.hasNextInt());
      {
           userValues[i]=scnr.nextInt(); // this line is giving me the error
      }     


      if (userValues[i]>=0)
      count = count +1;
}






if (userValues[10]==0) {
int outp = count / 2 + 1;
System.out.println(userValues[outp]);
//}

else 
System.out.println("Too many inputs");

   }
}
```

Comment: Typo. Remove the semicolon at `if (scnr.hasNextInt());` Note that if the next input is not an `int`, you need to **consume** it or you won't get any values.

Comment: If you are accessing 10th index of array , It should be 9 because size is 10

Comment: that was it, thank you Elliott!

Answer (score 0):

- Remove semicolon from `If` condition.

  ```
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
    if (scnr.hasNextInt()) //remove semicolon

     {
     userValues[i]=scnr.nextInt();   error
    }

    if (userValues[i]>=0)
        count = count +1;
   }
  ```
- Array size is 10.
- If you are accessing 10th index of array, It should be 9 or You will get **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** exception

  ```
     int[] userValues = new int[10]; //array size is 10

     if (userValues[9]==0) {
          int outp = count / 2 + 1;
           System.out.println(userValues[outp]);
         }
  ```